# How can locate the element in the sub frame with nightwatch?

Tags: nightwatch.js

for example,I try to locate the element in the webtour,see the html like this:

```html
<frameset>
    <frame name="a"></frame>
    <frame name="b"><input name="login"/></frame>
</frameset>
```

and **there is no id attribute**,I try to use .frame(0).frame(1),but it didn't work,can somebody give me a little hint?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Nightwatch

With `.frameParent` you need to change focus on parent frame and then choose which frame you want to have focused:

```
this.testFrames = function (browser) {
  browser
    .frame(0) // first frame
    .frameParent()
    .frame(1) // second frame
    .frameParent()
}
```

Docs: https://nightwatchjs.org/api/frameParent.html

Now, to fill the input field inside second frame:

```
this.testInputFrame = function (browser) {
  browser
    .frame(1) // second frame
    .waitForElementVisible('input[name="login"]')
    .setValue('input[name="login"], 'user123')
    .frameParent()
}
```